# php move_uploaded_file() image permission issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

my code is successfully working for upload images. but problem is it fails to display uploaded images. i checked image path output is correct in html source view but image till not displaying. i think its a file permission issue. how can i upload these images with read write full permission so images can display properly.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_img"])) {
$target_dir = "../assets/img/temp_img/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$randstr = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 3);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_dir.$randstr)) 
{

    $q =mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO temp_img (product_img_url) VALUES ('$randstr')");
    if ($q>0) {
      echo "<br>The file has been uploaded.";
    }
} else {echo "<br>Error uploading your file.";}
}
//show all uploaded images
$q2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT product_img_url FROM temp_img");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q2)) {
    $product_img_url = $row['product_img_url'];
    $img_format = ".jpg";
    $broken_url = "assets/img/temp_img/";


echo '<img src="'.$main_url.$broken_url.$product_img_url.$img_format.'" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">';

}
```

[image missing picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xesnP.png)

Comment: you save to `../assets/...`, but point the `<img>` at `assets/...`. is that a correct relative path? unless this script is running in your document root, those will be two entirely different paths, and if it IS at your document root, then `../assets` will be OUTSIDE the document root.

Comment: <img src="http://localhost/projects/smartview/assets/img/temp_img/D7i.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"><img src="http://localhost/projects/smartview/assets/img/temp_img/OwL.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">

Comment: above is my output with full path but image still not display. but when i copy a simple image menually from else where then it works. uploaded image only not works. and i found there is file permission issue. i think chmod() required but how can i add it in my script?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following link will help you change permissions of your file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Note:
 1.check whether the uploaded file is in specified folder.

2.try setting the path without "../" in the variable *targetdir*

Comment: <img src="localhost/projects/smartview/assets/img/temp_img/D7i.jpg"; class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"><img src="localhost/projects/smartview/assets/img/temp_img/OwL.jpg"; class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"> my html output is 100% fine its issue about uploaded file permission.

Comment: Ok then. Have a great day